# Set var to .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I would like to set a variable to the text of an element when that element is clicked:

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    var selected;
    var selected = this.text();
});
```

I've looked at the documentation and I believe this should work. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: In your example you declared `selected` twice (used `var` twice). You should only use `var` when you first declare the variable.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: You're absolutely correct. It's harmless, though (that's actually in the specification). You're free to use `var` redundantly, it's completely ignored. (Just the `var` part; any initializer on it is treated as an assignment.) More here: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html

Comment: @T.J. Thanks a lot :). Never tried to write it twice, I have learnt something new. **So:** it is possible, but never a good idea, because it is illogical.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Yup, that's my take. :-) (*Here* I figure it was a typo, but still worth your flagging it up.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var selected = $(this).text();
```

If no luck, maybe it's form element so it has value:

```
var selected = $(this).val();
```

If **still** no luck let us know what is `clickme` (div? span?) and try this as "last resort":

```
var selected = $(this).html();
```

Comment: @Thomas: `this` within the `click` handler refers to the raw DOM node, but `text` is a function of jQuery instances. that's why Shadow Wizard has you passing `this` into `$()` to wrap the DOM node in a jQuery instance and get access to the jQuery functions.

Comment: Thanks @T.J for the clarification.. in case this is form element you can use the raw DOM node: `var selected = this.value;` :)

Answer (score 1):

if .clickme is input or textarea :

```
var selected;
$('.clickme').click(function()
{
    selected = $(this).val();
});
```

Other :

```
var selected;
$('.clickme').click(function()
{
    selected = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `this` with the jQuery object...

```
var selected = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your listener is on a button, IE doesn't know the difference between the *text* and *value* properties and jQuery doesn't fix it, *getAttribute* doesn't help either. You need to use *getAttributeNode*:

```
<button value="the value"
 onclick="alert(this.getAttributeNode('value').value);">The text</button>
```